# React | Redux-Form | Field Assign state to the field

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form

I am trying create custom buttons to change the value of the input field with state, but when the form is submitted the field is not showing in form values. I am using Field from 'redux-form' and when user clicks on button the role is changing in state and the input field change value, but it is not showing in form values, but if type it mannually (without state) it works fine

```
class Registration extends React.Component {
    state = {role: 'student'};

    renderInput = ({input, label, type, placeholder, meta, role}) => {
        return (
            <div>
                <label htmlFor="">{label}</label>
                <input className="d-block w-100" {...input} type={type} placeholder={placeholder} value={role}/>
                {this.renderError(meta)}
            </div>
        )
    };

    render() {
        let role = this.state.role;

        return (
            <div className="mt-2 mx-auto">
            <Field type="text" name="user_role" component={this.renderInput}
                   label="Ваша роль" placeholder="****"/>

            <div className="mt-2 row w-100">
                <div className="col ml-3 m-0 p-0">
                    <div className={`btn btn-black-outline w-100 role-student-${role}`}
                         onClick={() => {
                             this.setState({role: 'student'})
                         }}>Ученик
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div className="col m-0 p-0">
                    <div className={`btn btn-black-outline w-100 role-teacher-${role}`} onClick={() => {
                        this.setState({role: 'teacher'})
                    }}>Учитель
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```